# How To Store Answers To Password Reset Questions?

Tags: security, passwords, normalization

I'm still a Newbie to a lot of the *best practices* and that is the reason to my question.

My current project is a password reset system.
Right now I have the questions stored in a table with ID's for each question. 
I'm thinking of just storing the question ID and the  answers for the questions in the same table as the user data.

My user table columns would look like this:

### ID | FName | LName | Email | Pass | ResQuestions | ResAnswers

Or should I make a separate table to store the information.

### UserID | ResQuestions | ResAnswers

What should I be worrying about having messy tables? 
Or should I just ditch the whole question system and have the reset only based on email vitrifaction?

*Note: that Both the password and the Answers are encrypted.*

A comment always helps more than a down vote, thank you for reading.

Comment: The reason for avoiding messy tables is usually performance related, or to avoid redundancy in the data.  If you aren't worried about it, then denormalizing shouldn't be a big issue.

Comment: @MichaelGardner Okay thank you. I just don't want to come back one day and think its just a mess of code, and have to redo it all.

Comment: Just be sure to document the design decision accordingly :)  As far as choosing email verification vs challenge questions, since the logic is already written for the questions, I would stick with that.  You can always increase the pool of questions and remove the 'easy' to guess ones from the pool to help with account security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for avoiding messy tables is usually performance related, or to avoid redundancy in the data. If you aren't worried about it, then denormalizing shouldn't be a big issue, just be sure to document the design decision accordingly to help with code maintenance.

Now normalizing your tables would allow you to more easily implement a multi-question challenge logic, where the user would be asked more than one question to verify identity.

As far as choosing email verification vs challenge questions, since the logic is already written for the questions, I would stick with that. You can always increase the pool of questions and remove the 'easy' to guess ones from the pool to help with account security.  Try to avoid questions that a friend might easily know (pets, birthplaces, etc).